# PHP/Wordpress: how to amend foreach() to output my array in a specific way

Tags: php, arrays, json, wordpress, foreach

MAJOR EDIT: Reframing question as this might be easier to solve...

I am trying to generate JSON microdata using PHP code in Wordpress. I'm currently using the foreach() method to cycle through a list of posts on a page, put their thumbnail, title and link data into an array, and I'll later encode that array into JSON microdata. However, the array I've assembled using foreach() doesn't output the data how I want.

I've spent hours trying to get this section of data to output correctly, but to no avail.

--

What I want to achieve (using print_r() to view and test my PHP code) - e.g. Instead of index numbers like `[0]`. `[1]` etc., I want each array to output `[associatedMedia]` instead as below:

```
Array
(
    [associatedMedia] => Array
        (
            [image] => http://www.website.com/thumbnail.jpg
            [name] => post title
            [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post
        )
    [associatedMedia] => Array
        (
            [image] => http://www.website.com/second-thumbnail.jpg
            [name] => second post title
            [url] => http://www.website.com/the-second-post
        ) 
    // And so on...
)
```

My current result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [image] => http://www.website.com/first-thumbnail.jpg
            [name] => first post title
            [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post-one
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [image] => http://www.website.com/second-thumbnail.jpg
            [name] => second post title
            [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post-two
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [image] => http://www.website.com/third-thumbnail.jpg
            [name] => third post title
            [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post-three
        ) // And so on...
)
```

My foreach method:

```
// other PHP  code

global $post;
global $wp_query;

$category = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
$args = array( 'category' => $category->cat_ID );
$posts = get_posts( $args );

$post_details = array();
$i = 0;

foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata($post);   
    $thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'thumbnail' );
    $post_thumbnails['image'] = $thumb_url[0];
    $post_titles['name'] = get_the_title();
    $post_links['url'] = get_permalink();

    $post_details[$i]['image'] = $post_thumbnails['image'];
    $post_details[$i]['name'] = $post_titles['name'];
    $post_details[$i]['url'] = $post_links['url'];
    $i++;
};

wp_reset_postdata(); 

print_r($post_details);
```

I'm only beginning to get into more advanced programming, and I'm sure my code above will look crude. So any help or tips on how I can shorten it would be appreciated.

EDIT: More `$post` related code added

Comment: where do you have `$posts`from? Could you give us the result of `var_dump($posts)` ?

Comment: the global `$post` variable is relative to the page/post you are on. If you are on an archive page, try looking into the WordPress Loop and the `WP_Query()` object. https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop

Comment: I've included this part of my code to my original post now. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$array_details['associatedMedia'][$i] = $post_details[$i];
```

instead of

```
$array_details['associatedMedia'] = $post_details[$i];
```

**Update :**

Keys of array elements should be unique.
Use any of the below format to get the desired results.

```
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    ....
    $array_details['associatedMedia'][$i] = $post_details[$i];
    i++;
}
```

Results :

```
Array
(
   ['associatedMedia'] => Array(   
       [0] => Array(
                [image] => http://www.website.com/first-thumbnail.jpg
                [name] => first post title
                [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post-one
        )
        [1] => Array(
                [image] => http://www.website.com/second-thumbnail.jpg
                [name] => second post title
                [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post-two
        )
        [2] => Array(
                [image] => http://www.website.com/third-thumbnail.jpg
                [name] => third post title
                [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post-three
        ) // And so on...
  )
)
```

OR

```
foreach( $posts as $post ) {
    ....
    $array_details[$i]['associatedMedia']= $post_details[$i];
    i++;
}
```

Results :

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array(
        ['associatedMedia'] => Array( 
                [image] => http://www.website.com/first-thumbnail.jpg
                [name] => first post title
                [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post-one
            )
    )

  [1] => Array(
       ['associatedMedia'] => Array( 
                [image] => http://www.website.com/second-thumbnail.jpg
                [name] => second post title
                [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post-two
        )
    )

 [2] => Array(
      ['associatedMedia'] => Array( 
                [image] => http://www.website.com/third-thumbnail.jpg
                [name] => third post title
                [url] => http://www.website.com/the-post-three
        )
    ) // And so on...

)
```

Comment: Thank you Ravinder, see my edited post above. Your solution gave me the result in the middle grey box - So all I need to find out now is how to make the index number appear as `[associatedMedia]` instead :)

Comment: You cannot have the multiple array elements with same key. Array keys should be unique. If you want to use the same key for each array elements, you will end up with single element in the array.

Comment: I see. So how can I create multiple arrays with the 'associatedMedia' key, so when I encode the JSON data, it comes out something like this:

    "mainContentOfPage" => array(
    "@type" => "WebPageElement",
    "associatedMedia" => array(
        'image' => // info,
        'name' => // info,
        'url' => // info/
    ),
    "associatedMedia" => array(
        'image' => // info,
        'name' => // info,
        'url' => // info
    ),
    // Etc.
    )

Comment: I've just seen that you updated your post. I'll give your suggestions a go and see how they show up in Googles Structured Data Testing Tool  :)

Comment: Well I've just tested the following code in the testing tool:
`$array_details['associatedMedia'][$i] = $post_details[$i];
    i++;`
And it somehow reads the JSON microdata exactly how I want it to. Problem solved, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just remove $i++ to foreach closing bracket.
You define $i=0
With first iteration of foreach it increments to 1.
Then you assign $array_details['associatedMedia'] = $post_details[$i],
in fact  $array_details['associatedMedia'][0] = $post_details[1];

Sorry for my "technical" english. (:

UPDATE

```
foreach( $posts as $key => $post ) {
```

...

```
$array_details[$key]['associatedMedia'] = $post_details[$i]
```

Comment: Thanks user2781327, your answer also gave me the result in the middle grey box in my edited post above - so do you know how I can replace the index number with `[associatedMedia]`? Almost there :)